# Como pegar um valor de um código JavaScript e usá-lo no PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, variáveis

Ppreciso que quando a largura do navegador estiver entre alguns valores estipulados, a minha variável `$colunas` assuma valores diferentes.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$largura = "<script type =text/javascript>var largura =  document.body.clientWidth; document.write(largura); </script>";
echo $largura, '<br>';
$colunas = 0;
if ($largura > 1800) {
    $colunas = 4;
}
else if (($largura >= 1450) and ($largura <= 1800)) {
    $colunas = 3;
}
else if($largura <= 1449){
    $colunas = 2;
}
echo $colunas;
```

Porém a minha variável `$colunas` sempre recebe o valor igual a 2, independente de eu alterar a largura do navegador.

Comment: Largura do navegador? Creio que isso deve ser feito com javascript, senão você terá que mandar carregar a qualquer alteração.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto não existe, você está misturando PHP com JavaScript. Elas são linguagens diferentes e executam de forma totalmente separada. Não só em momentos diferentes, mas em locais diferentes. Uma não é continuação da outra.

Se quer fazer isto, tem que obter a informação no JS dentro da página já existente e enviar isto para o PHP usar de alguma forma. Mas na verdade isto não é o ideal e nem parece que deseja fazer isto. De fato esta é uma forma antiga de resolver este problema.

A solução é resolver tudo no lado do cliente, com CSS e eventualmente JS. O PHP só deve gerar o conteúdo, não deve ser responsável pelo formato de apresentação da página.

Tem informações sobre isto aqui no site, mas se tiver alguma dúvida específica, abra uma pergunta sobre isto.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o PHP é executado no servidor, antes do javascript que executa no seu navegador (ou o do cliente), por isso o valor de $largura será sempre o mesmo.

Procure ler sobre https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side e https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lado_cliente